# How to know what element is mandatory if it has miniOccurs="0" in UBL

Tags: xml, xsd, ubl

Here is my XML test code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Invoice xmlns:qdt="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:QualifiedDatatypes-2" xmlns:ccts="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CoreComponentParameters-2" xmlns:stat="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:DocumentStatusCode-1.0" xmlns:cbc="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonBasicComponents-2" xmlns:cac="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonAggregateComponents-2" xmlns:udt="urn:un:unece:uncefact:data:draft:UnqualifiedDataTypesSchemaModule:2" xmlns="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:Invoice-2">
    <cbc:ID>A00095678</cbc:ID>
    <cbc:IssueDate>2005-06-21</cbc:IssueDate>
    <cac:AccountingSupplierParty>
    </cac:AccountingSupplierParty>
    <cac:AccountingCustomerParty>
    </cac:AccountingCustomerParty>
    <cac:LegalMonetaryTotal>
        <cbc:PayableAmount currencyID="GBP">107.50</cbc:PayableAmount>
    </cac:LegalMonetaryTotal>
    <cac:InvoiceLine>
        <cbc:ID>A</cbc:ID>
        <cbc:LineExtensionAmount currencyID="GBP">100.00</cbc:LineExtensionAmount>
        <cac:Item>
        </cac:Item>
    </cac:InvoiceLine>
</Invoice>
```

I put the only elements that were required due to having minOccurs="1" in the UBL.xsd file.

When I try to validate my XML on [this site](https://www.itb.ec.europa.eu/invoice/upload)

```
[BR-01]-An Invoice shall have a Specification identifier (BT-24).
[BR-04]-An Invoice shall have an Invoice type code (BT-3).
[BR-05]-An Invoice shall have an Invoice currency code (BT-5).
[BR-06]-An Invoice shall contain the Seller name (BT-27).
[BR-07]-An Invoice shall contain the Buyer name (BT-44).
[BR-08]-An Invoice shall contain the Seller postal address.
[BR-10]-An Invoice shall contain the Buyer postal address (BG-8).
[BR-CO-18]-An Invoice shall at least have one VAT breakdown group (BG-23).
```

I understand what the error mean, my question is more :
What is the UBL.xsd file is saying that these elements are mandatory? I will have to generate files regarding other .xsd files and I'd like to understand what elements are mandatory.

Comment: While asking an XSD question you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) Well-formed input XML.
(2) Your logic, and XSD that tried to implement it.
(3) XSD processor and its conformance with the XSD standards: 1.0, or 1.1.

Comment: **"What is the UBL.xsd file is saying that these elements are mandatory?"** This does not make sense. You should clarify or elaborate further what you mean.

Comment: I don't know anything about UBL, but it is not unusual for a specification to impose semantic rules alongside the structural rules in the XSD schema. Sometimes there is both an XSD schema and a set of semantic rules expressed in Schematron.

Comment: If it has minoccurs="0" then that element is optional according to the xsd. As per Martin's answer, those validation messages are not from the schema.

Comment: At least let is know what type of UBL you are trying to build. The different flavors have different business rules allthough they share the same XML schema. Business rules are enforced by the schematron schema

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think these errors are from Schematron validation, see e.g. https://github.com/ConnectingEurope/eInvoicing-EN16931/blob/validation-1.3.10/ubl/schematron/preprocessed/EN16931-UBL-validation-preprocessed.sch#L79.

Comment: Yes, this is correct, the message is from a schematron validation