# What to put in customizationID in UBL document and where to get this information

Tags: xml, xsd, schematron, ubl

I am trying to generate Invoice UBL XML file according to [this XSD file](http://docs.oasis-open.org/ubl/os-UBL-2.1/xsd/maindoc/UBL-Invoice-2.1.xsd)  and [this schematron](https://github.com/ConnectingEurope/eInvoicing-EN16931/blob/validation-1.3.10/ubl/schematron/preprocessed/EN16931-UBL-validation-preprocessed.sch#L79). Once it is generated I am validating it [here](https://www.itb.ec.europa.eu/invoice/upload).

So, according to the schematron, I must have a CustomizationID in my XML file :

```
<assert id="BR-01" flag="fatal" test="normalize-space(cbc:CustomizationID) != ''">[BR-01]-An Invoice shall have a Specification identifier (BT-24).   </assert>
```

So I tried to find what kind of value was expected in CustomizationID, so I found [here](https://docs.peppol.eu/poacc/billing/3.0/syntax/ubl-invoice/cbc-CustomizationID/) that the default value was `urn:cen.eu:en16931:2017#compliant#urn:fdc:peppol.eu:2017:poacc:billing:3.0`, so even thought it might not **always** be the right value to put in, it should **at least** be enough to validate the UBL document, am I wrong?

But if I put this value in my XML file and try to validate it, I have an error I don't understand.

Here is my XML file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Invoice xmlns:qdt="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:QualifiedDatatypes-2" xmlns:ccts="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CoreComponentParameters-2" xmlns:stat="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:DocumentStatusCode-1.0" xmlns:cbc="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonBasicComponents-2" xmlns:cac="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonAggregateComponents-2" xmlns:udt="urn:un:unece:uncefact:data:draft:UnqualifiedDataTypesSchemaModule:2" xmlns="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:Invoice-2">
    <cbc:ID>A00095678</cbc:ID>
    <cbc:IssueDate>2005-06-21</cbc:IssueDate>
    <cbc:CustomizationID>urn:cen.eu:en16931:2017#compliant#urn:fdc:peppol.eu:2017:poacc:billing:3.0</cbc:CustomizationID>
    <cbc:InvoiceTypeCode>SalesInvoice</cbc:InvoiceTypeCode>
    <cac:AccountingSupplierParty>
    </cac:AccountingSupplierParty>
    <cac:AccountingCustomerParty>
    </cac:AccountingCustomerParty>
    <cac:LegalMonetaryTotal>
        <cbc:PayableAmount currencyID="GBP">107.50</cbc:PayableAmount>
    </cac:LegalMonetaryTotal>
    <cac:InvoiceLine>
        <cbc:ID>A</cbc:ID>
        <cbc:LineExtensionAmount currencyID="GBP">100.00</cbc:LineExtensionAmount>
        <cac:Item>
        </cac:Item>
    </cac:InvoiceLine>
</Invoice>
```

When I try to validate my XML file, I have this error :

> cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with
> element
> '{"urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonBasicComponents-2":CustomizationID}'.
> One of
> '{"urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonBasicComponents-2":IssueTime,
> "urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonBasicComponents-2":DueDate,
> "urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonBasicComponents-2":InvoiceTypeCode,
> "urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonBasicComponents-2":Note,
> "urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonBasicComponents-2":TaxPointDate,
> "urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonBasicComponents-2":DocumentCurrencyCode,
> "urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonBasicComponents-2":TaxCurrencyCode,
> "urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonBasicComponents-2":PricingCurrencyCode,
> "urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonBasicComponents-2":PaymentCurrencyCode,
> "urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonBasicComponents-2":PaymentAlternativeCurrencyCode,
> "urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonBasicComponents-2":AccountingCostCode,
> "urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonBasicComponents-2":AccountingCost,
> "urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonBasicComponents-2":LineCountNumeric,
> "urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonBasicComponents-2":BuyerReference,
> "urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonAggregateComponents-2":InvoicePeriod,
> "urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonAggregateComponents-2":OrderReference,
> "urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonAggregateComponents-2":BillingReference,
> "urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonAggregateComponents-2":DespatchDocumentReference,
> "urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonAggregateComponents-2":ReceiptDocumentReference,
> "urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonAggregateComponents-2":StatementDocumentReference,
> "urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonAggregateComponents-2":OriginatorDocumentReference,
> "urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonAggregateComponents-2":ContractDocumentReference,
> "urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonAggregateComponents-2":AdditionalDocumentReference,
> "urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonAggregateComponents-2":ProjectReference,
> "urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonAggregateComponents-2":Signature,
> "urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonAggregateComponents-2":AccountingSupplierParty}'
> is expected.

I don't understand the error and how to fix it. First, how is it not a valid content if it is the default value, and second, why is it expecting any of these other fields instead? Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Basically it is telling you that is was not expecting CustomizationID at that point, but one if the other elements that it is listing (so they must all be optional except for the last one AccountingSupplierParty), so if you remove CustomizationID, then the next element will be InvoiceTypeCode and it will validate.

[image: Image of Schema]

CustomizationID is an optional element `<xsd:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" ref="cbc:CustomizationID">`, and the proceeding two elements UBLExtensions and UBLVersionID are also optional, and as you don't have those, CustomizationID should be first, before ID (which is mandatory `<xsd:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" ref="cbc:ID">`.

So it should look more like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Invoice xmlns:qdt="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:QualifiedDatatypes-2" xmlns:ccts="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CoreComponentParameters-2" xmlns:stat="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:DocumentStatusCode-1.0" xmlns:cbc="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonBasicComponents-2" xmlns:cac="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonAggregateComponents-2" xmlns:udt="urn:un:unece:uncefact:data:draft:UnqualifiedDataTypesSchemaModule:2" xmlns="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:Invoice-2">
    <cbc:CustomizationID>urn:cen.eu:en16931:2017#compliant#urn:fdc:peppol.eu:2017:poacc:billing:3.0</cbc:CustomizationID>
    <cbc:ID>A00095678</cbc:ID>
    <cbc:IssueDate>2005-06-21</cbc:IssueDate>
    <cbc:InvoiceTypeCode>SalesInvoice</cbc:InvoiceTypeCode>
    <cac:AccountingSupplierParty>
    </cac:AccountingSupplierParty>
    <cac:AccountingCustomerParty>
    </cac:AccountingCustomerParty>
    <cac:LegalMonetaryTotal>
        <cbc:PayableAmount currencyID="GBP">107.50</cbc:PayableAmount>
    </cac:LegalMonetaryTotal>
    <cac:InvoiceLine>
        <cbc:ID>A</cbc:ID>
        <cbc:LineExtensionAmount currencyID="GBP">100.00</cbc:LineExtensionAmount>
        <cac:Item>
        </cac:Item>
    </cac:InvoiceLine>
</Invoice>
```

That still fails in Schematron, but not about that field.

Comment: Let me tell you that if i remove CustomizationID, it doesn't validate as i've already tried it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76863164/how-to-know-what-element-is-mandatory-if-it-has-minioccurs-0-in-ubl/76866189#76866189). 
And also, the ubl example you linked does not validate either haha

Comment: @aprotiere That is strange as CustomizationdID is optional (MinOccurs = 0)

Comment: @aprotiere I've updated my answer with more details

Comment: It still doesn't validate, I don't know what to do tbh

Comment: And btw, CustomizationID is optional according to the XSD, but not according to the [schematron](https://github.com/ConnectingEurope/eInvoicing-EN16931/blob/validation-1.3.10/ubl/schematron/preprocessed/EN16931-UBL-validation-preprocessed.sch#L79)

Comment: @aprotiere Even so, you have it in the wrong place, hence you getting the schema validation error.

Comment: Also I notice that the Schemtron validation is expecting release 1.13.10, not sure how that relates to the UBL version